# Is the scope being changed here or is it something else?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, scope

I'm pretty inexperienced with JavaScript so I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

This works perfectly:

```
myarray = [];

myarray.push(1);
```

This works perfectly too:

```
myarray = [];

function example(){
  myarray.push(1);
}

example();
```

This doesn't work at all:

```
myarray = [];

function example(){
  myarray.push(1);
}

$(window).load(function(){
  example();
});
```

Am I changing the scope or something with `$(window).load(function(){...`?

How can I make `example()` execute like it did in the second snippet in the third snippet?

Comment: Did you actually load jQuery?

Comment: it should work.try adding jquery file.see your error in console if any.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem: http://jsbin.com/refegiviho/1/ (after adding an alert so the value of the array is revealed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

window.onload event is fired when complete DOM is loaded therefore in third case example() will run later and other code will run earlier.

I reproduced your problem and may be i am incorrect but below is the running code whatever i have observed

```
myarray = [];

function example(){
  myarray.push(1);
}

$(window).load(function(){

  example();
});

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(myarray);
},100);
```

If you got something else please answered your own question... I am interested to know deeper about

Comment: I've spent literal hours trying to figure out what I was doing wrong and all that time I forgot about this. Thank you so much.